# Why is a manual setup time different to the current Time

Tags: javascript, time, syntax

Where is the difference between a manual set up time and a current set up time?

According to this syntax:

`new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds)`

... it shouldn't make any difference.

```js
var now = new Date();
var alarmTime = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(),        now.getDay(), now.getHours(), now.getMinutes(), now.getSeconds(), now.getMilliseconds());
document.write(alarmTime.getTime() == now.getTime());
```

Comment: works fine here (FF 47). where/how are you executing this?

Comment: 52.0.2743.84   Google Chrome outputs false :/

Comment: so start debugging: console.log() both getTime() values and see what you're getting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling the wrong method. It is `now.getDate()` and not `now.getDay()`.

`now.getDay()` will return current day (5).
`now.getDate()` will return current date (29).

Fixed:

```js
var now = new Date();
var alarmTime = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(),now.getDate(), now.getHours(), now.getMinutes(), now.getSeconds(),now.getMilliseconds());
document.write(alarmTime.getTime() == now.getTime());
```

Comment: Thankyou for your answer !

Comment: Totally ! Answer verified;)

Answer (score 0):

The getDay() method returns the day of the week (from 0 to 6) for the specified date.

The getMonth() method returns the month (from 0 to 11) for the specified date, according to local time.